# How to create a new window and set UseShellExecute false in powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell

The requirement is a bit strange, I've encountered a strange stuck problem in multi-thread in powershell. So I want to create a new window and don't use shell Execute. But I cannot make it with below code, the window doesn't show up.
$approot is desktop, in start.bat, just do "dir /s .\"
I want the dir result shows in another window instead of the window execute this script, and I don't want use shell execute.

```
$startInfo = New-Object system.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$startInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$startinfo.FileName = $env:ComSpec
$startInfo.CreateNoWindow = $false
$startInfo.Arguments = "/c cd /d $AppRoot & call start.bat"
$process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$process.StartInfo = $startInfo
$process.Start() | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you set `.UseShellExecute` to `$False`, you cannot start your command in a *new* console window** (the only thing you can do in that case is to run a console-based command *hidden*, by setting `.CreateNoWindow` to `$true`; at its default, `$false`, the command runs in the *caller's* console window).

Therefore, you may as well use `Start-Process`, which leaves `.UseShellExecute` at its default, `$True`<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
Start-Process $env:ComSpec -Args '/k', "cd /d `"$AppRoot`" & call start.bat"
```

<sup>To promote good habits, `$AppRoot` is enclosed in *embedded* double quotes (escaped as `` `" ``) to properly deal with paths containing spaces. While this is not strictly necessary with `cmd.exe`'s `cd`, it is with virtually all other commands / programs.</sup>

Note that I'm using `/k` rather than `/c` as the `cmd.exe` (`$env:ComSpec`) switch to ensure that the new windows stays open.

---

**If setting `.UseShellExecute` to `$False` is a must, use `conhost.exe` to explicitly create a new window (requires Windows 10):**

```
$process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$process.startInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$process.startinfo.FileName = 'conhost.exe'
$process.startInfo.Arguments = "cmd /k cd /d `"$AppRoot`" & call start.bat"
$null = $process.Start()
```

On other flavors / versions of Windows, **you may be able to use P/Invoke to call the [`CreateProcess()` Windows API function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms682425) directly**, using the [`CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/process-creation-flags).

---

<sup>[1]</sup>

- Note that certain `Start-Process` parameters, such as `-NoNewWindow` and `-Credential`, require that `.UseShellExecute` be set to `$False`, in which case the `CreateProcess()` WinAPI function is used (rather than `ShellExecute()`) behind the scenes.
- Also note that in .NET *Core* `.UseShellExecute`'s default is now `$False`, but PowerShell Core's `Start-Process` still defaults to `$True` to match Windows PowerShell's behavior.

Comment: @james: You may be able to use P/Invoke to call the `CreateProcess()` Windows API function directly, but that's substantially more work - please see my update for pointers.

Comment: @james: Re `$AppRoot`: good point, the double quotes aren't needed for `cd`, but virtually all other commands and programs do require them, so I left them in there to promote good habits; however, I've added a  note about the `cd` exception.

Comment: Really appreciate your help, use P/Invoke works well in my case, is it same with  process.start() API in CPU load?

Comment: @james: My _guess_ is that they perform similarly (.NET ultimately calls the WinAPI too, there may be overhead related to P/Invoke calls), but if you're creating the P/Invoke code dynamically from PowerShell with `Add-Type`, you'll pay a one-time initial performance penalty for its compilation.