# execute a script block on a remote server

Tags: powershell

I have written a script which works fine on the local server. However I would like to run the script block on a remote server. Here's the script block that's that runs fine locally. Can I use Invoke-Command to embed the below script block and run it on a remote server?

```
$Folder = Read-Host "Enter the folder name"
$FilePath = "E:\$Folder\capture.bat"
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "qtestwest01"

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {$pt = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;}
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {$pt.FileName = $using:FilePath;}
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {$pt.UseShellExecute = $false;}
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {$pt.RedurectStandardInput = $true;}
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {$e = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($pt);}
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {$e.StandardInput.WriteLie("`n")}
```

Comment: Yes............

Comment: please, **_Read The Friendly Manual_** by taking a look at `Get-Help Invoke-Command` for some ideas ... [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks for your response. sorry I don't know how to embed this in a invoke-command. Would you be kind enough to provide me a snippet of the invoke-command.

Comment: @signalhouse, for `powershell Invoke-Command`, Google returns `"About 1,000,000 results"`. Just searching `stackoverflow.com` returns `"9,137 results"`. Surely there is something in ther for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty straight forward:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "qtestwest01"

$SB = 
{
    $pt = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
    $pt.FileName = "E:\testscripts\capture.bat";
    $pt.UseShellExecute = $false;
    $pt.RedirectStandardInput = $true;
    $e = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($pt);
    $e.StandardInput.WriteLine("`n")
}

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $SB
```

An aside: You may want to look at `Start-Process -PassThru`. Though I'm not sure you can set UseShellExecute using that pattern.  There are some details about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52138307/4749264) , but I didn't give it a thorough reading.

### Update

Responding to your implementation and the parameter question, repeatedly calling `Invoke-Command` is unnecessary. You're calling into the same session so it's functionally the same thing, but everything you need is available so you can run a single command.  The `$Using:` modifier can be used in a prefabricated ScriptBlock so long as the script block is used with certain cmdlets, including and maybe primarily `Invoke-Command`.

A new example:

```
$FilePath = "C:\windows\System32\notepad.exe"
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server1"

$SB = 
{
    $pt = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
    $pt.FileName = $Using:FilePath;
    $pt.UseShellExecute = $false;
    $pt.RedirectStandardInput = $true;
    $e = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($pt);
    $e.StandardInput.WriteLine("`n")
}

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $SB
```

A second method of passing parameters into a script block is to use the `Invoke-Command -ArgumentList` parameter:

Example:

```
$FilePath = "C:\windows\System32\notepad.exe"
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server1"

$SB = 
{
    $pt = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
    $pt.FileName = $args[0] ;
    $pt.UseShellExecute = $false;
    $pt.RedirectStandardInput = $true;
    $e = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($pt);
    $e.StandardInput.WriteLine("`n")
}

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock $SB -ArgumentList $FilePath
```

And, Either approach, `$Using` or `$args[0]` will work even if cite the script block inline with the command:

Example:

```
$FilePath = "C:\windows\System32\notepad.exe"
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Server1"

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ArgumentList $FilePath -ScriptBlock {
    $pt = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
    $pt.FileName = $args[0] ;
    $pt.UseShellExecute = $false;
    $pt.RedirectStandardInput = $true;
    $e = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($pt);
    $e.StandardInput.WriteLine("`n")
}
```

Notes:

`-ComputerName` argument name and `$FilePath` value were changed in these examples just so I could test in my environment.

The use of `$FilePath` instead of `$Folder`.  So far as I can tell `$pt.FileName` property needs a the full path.  This was either mis-typed or in error in your last sample.  $FilePath because of the `-FilePath` parameter on `Start-Process`.

Comment: Thank you Steve. I tried your approach and it works. Is there a way I can parameterize the following statement. $pt.FileName = "E:\$folder\capture.bat";

Comment: You can use a parameter like `-Arguments <FileName>` in the `New-Object` command.  Let me know how it goes.  Mark the question as answered if you're ok...

Comment: Thank you Steve. I followed a slightly different approach. Used a separate invoke-command statement for each line of code that I want to execute remotely.

Comment: Thank you Steve. I tried your 2nd solution and it worked like a charm. Yes the value defined inside $FilePath variable is a typo on my script.

Answer (score 0):

```
$folder = 'testscripts'
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "qtestwest01"

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {$pt = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;}
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {$pt.FileName = $using:folder;}
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {$pt.UseShellExecute = $false;}
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {$pt.RedurectStandardInput = $true;}
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {$e = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($pt);}
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {$e.StandardInput.WriteLie("`n")}
```

Comment: I'm glad this is working but it's unnecessary to repeatedly call `Invoke-Command`.  Moreover, the way it is written the filename won't be an executable file it's just a flat string.  Perhaps I didn't understand your parameterize question...  The using scope modifier is available in a prefabricated script block so long as the scriptblock is used with certain cmdlets `Invoke-cCommand` chief among them.  I'll update the answer with an additional sample.

Comment: Yes, I do feel that it's not a great solution (using multiple invoke-command statements). However I felt this is the most easiest way I could come up with being a rookie.

Comment: Check the answer I updated it, hopefully to give you a better understanding of the options for passing data into the script block.  I hope that also gives you some degree of comfort running `Invoke-Command` only once.  Please don't forget to mark the question answered.  Thanks.