# What is the difference between opening application by cmd/ps or by click?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I try to copy mozilla firefox bookmarks/passwords into a new windows profile during the login either by cmd or powershell, without copying the whole firefox profile: The script opens firefox (to create a profile), closes firefox and overwrite the created bookmarks with the old ones.

**Problem:**
The user opens firefox and in this moment firefox deletes the copied bookmarks/passwords and creates new ones.
In case the user opens and closes firefox manually, bookmarks/passwords can be copied by script and everything is fine.

Obviously there is a difference how Windows is handling files when opening by click or by cmdlet / powershell.

**Commands I tried to open firefox:**
[PS] `Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -PassThru` 
[CMD] `start "" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"` 
[CMD] `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"`

How can I imitate the opening of the application as if it is opened manually by the user?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You technically can't statically analyze how Explorer opens something because of shell extensions but that is unlikely to apply to .exe files so let us ignore that for now.

How does cmd.exe and batch files launch a process? `CreateProcess`.

How does Explorer launch a file? `ShellExecuteEx` most of the time.

That being said, in the case of .exe files, `ShellExecuteEx` might append to %path% and some other minor things but in the end it is going to end up calling `CreateProcess` to start the actual process.

I believe your problem is somewhere else, not in the difference between cmd.exe and Explorer.

- The files are locked because someone (Firefox still running?) has a open handle to the bookmarks?
- It could be a problem related to wrong the current directory? The current directory is locked by Windows so you can't replace it by deleting it.
- Firefox running update task started by the task scheduler during login at the exact same time as your login script?

You can get PowerShell to use `ShellExecuteEx` by setting `UseShellExecute` to $true before starting the process but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52138307/3501) it is already true by default <s>(assuming your PassThru parameter does not force it to false)</s>.

Comment: It does look like cmd.exes start tries CreateProcess first if it finds a %pathext% that smells like a .exe.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I didn't realize that  `CreateProcess()` can launch processes in a new console too (by using the `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag in the `dwCreationFlags` parameter), because that capability is hidden in the .NET APIs, where setting `.UseShellExecute` to `false` in a `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` instance invariably runs (console) applications in the _current_ console window. Is that what is happening? I've cleaned up my previous comments and will post a revised version that is hopefully correct now. Let me know if it isn't.

Comment: `cmd.exe`'s internal `start` command uses the `ShellExecuteEx`WinAPI function, but only for non-executables (executables are files with extensions listed in `%PATHEXT%`), as you've discovered. PowerShell's `Start-Process` cmdlet uses `ShellExecuteEx` by default, even for executables - except if any of the following parameters are used: `-Credential`, `-NoNewEnvironment`, `-LoadUserProfile`, `-RedirectStandardInput/Output/Error`, `-UseNewEnvironment`; note that `-PassThru` does _not_ change what WinAPI function is used.

Comment: I tried setting UseShellExecute to true, but that didn't make any difference. But I recognized, that closing Firefox manually, I have no problem any more. It seems, that your assumption with an open handle on files could be right. In the tasklist I cannot see any open firefox processes after I stopped the Process with `Stop-Process -Name "Firefox"`.